# Order of asynchronous execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, lodash, throttling

When I click 'CLICK ME' repeatedly and quickly, why is there a possibility that `` console.log(`===${innerCount}.2`); `` is executed earlier over `` console.log(`===${innerCount}.1`); ``

Here is the CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-blackburn-v4k5y4?file=/src/App.js:651-666

`throttle` is from `lodash`.

```
let count = 0;
const App = () => {
  const throttledFetchData = throttle(async (innerCount) => {
    const result = await callApi();
    console.log(`===${innerCount}.1`);
    return result;
  }, 100);

  const handleClick = throttle(async (e: any) => {
    count++;
    const innerCount = count;
    const result = await throttledFetchData(innerCount);
    console.log(`===${innerCount}.2`);
  }, 50);

  return (
    <div className='container' onClick={handleClick}>
      CLICK ME
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: console content]

[image: reproduce gif]

Why wrapping two throttle?

Because it was a mistake，I'm stuck with the order problem when I debug.

Why did not reproduce the problem?

It only appears when click very quickly.

Comment: Hint: change the interval on the `throttledFetchData` from `100` to `1000`. Do you see this more often? Why do you think that might be?

Comment: Look at the return value of `throttledFetchData(innerCount)`. It's not a promise - a `throttle()`d function does not return anything

Comment: I got it. The answer is indeed about「 the return value of throttledFetchData(innerCount)」, but It is a promise, you can console it out to prove it, the old promise will return if this turn of execute is cancelled. I change the interval on the throttledFetchData from 100 to 1000, and remove one of throttle(it is useless). You can try it here  https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lichterman-u0e2r1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

The second `throttle` is not relevant, the cause of the issue is the behaviour of the first `throttle`d function. In particular,

> The `func` is invoked with the last arguments provided to the throttled function. *Subsequent calls to the throttled function return the result of the last `func` invocation.*
>
> […] `func` is invoked on the trailing edge of the timeout […] if the throttled function is invoked more than once during the wait timeout.
>
> <sup>[lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle)</sup>

You can see this more clearly when you return the `innerCount`, not the `callApi()` result, from the throttled function, to identify which promise `handleClick` was waiting for:

```
const throttledFetchData = throttle(async (innerCount) => {
  await callApi();
  console.log(`===${innerCount}.1`);
  return innerCount;
}, 1000);

const handleClick = async (e) => {
  const innerCount = ++count;
  const result = await throttledFetchData(innerCount);
  console.log(`===${innerCount}.2 after ${result}`);
};
```

So what's happening when `handleClick` is called twice in quick succession:

1. - the first `handleClick` invocation calls `throttledFetchData(1)`
   - it immediately calls the throttled implementation ("on the leading edge") which starts waiting for `callApi()`
   - a promise is returned from `throttledFetchData(1)` and `await` suspends the execution of `handleClick`
2. - the second `handleClick` invocation calls `throttledFetchData(2)`
   - it does defer the execution until 1s after the first call has passed, but *immediately returns the promise from the first invocation*
   - the `await` in the second `handleClick` suspends execution until that *old* promise is settled
3. - after 1s has passed, the deferred execution calls the throttled implementation ("on the trailng edge") which starts waiting for a second `callApi()`
4. - the first `callApi()` promise fulfills and resumes execution
   - `===1.1` is logged and `1` is returned (fulfilling the promise)
   - the first `handleClick` is resumed and logs `===1.2 after 1`
   - the second `handleClick` is resumed and logs `===2.2 after 1`
5. - the second `callApi()` promise fulfills and resumes execution
   - `===2.1` is logged and `2` is returned, but nobody is waiting for that promise

Answer (score -1):

Don't know the entire context, but you can try using "useCallback" something like this

```
import { useCallback, useRef } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const countRef = useRef(0);

  const throttledFetchData = useCallback(
    throttle(async () => {
      const result = await callApi();
      console.log(`===${countRef.current}.1`);
      return result;
    }, 100),
    []
  );

  const handleScroll = useCallback(
    throttle((e) => {
      countRef.current++;
      throttledFetchData();
      console.log(`===${countRef.current}.2`);
    }, 50),
    [throttledFetchData]
  );

  return (
    <div className='container' onScroll={handleScroll}>
      SCROLL ME
    </div>
  );
};
```

The useCallback hook to memoizes the handleScroll and throttledFetchData functions. This helps prevent unnecessary re-rendering of the component and ensures that we are always working with the latest version of these functions.

I also added a countRef variable to keep track of the number of times handleScroll is called. This is done using the useRef hook, which creates a mutable variable that persists across re-renders.

Also, updated the event listener to listen for the "onScroll" event instead of the "onClick" event

Comment: While it's generally good advice not to call `throttle` for every render, this does not solve the OPs problem here